# linear interpolated fog (correct algorithm)?

Tags: math, 3d, linear-interpolation

So, my rough idea of linear interpolation applied to fog stems from the Wikipedia article and inspired this:

```
pixelcolor = (fogcolor - originalpixelcolor) / fogdistance * pixeldistance + originalpixelcolor
```

Unfortunately, the formula is incorrect.  What would a corrected version of this formula be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear interpolation would look like:

```
factor = pixeldistance / fogdistance; 
if factor > 1 then factor = 1; //Should be in a range 0..1 to avoid color distortion
pixelcolor = originalpixelcolor + (fogcolor - originalpixelcolor) * factor;
```

Comment: Well, I got it working by using a lerp function and screwing around, but congrats anyways.